# Why EF is pluralizing just one table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Im using entity framework database first approach to create the mapping of my objects to the database. 
I use the EF wizard to select some tables and generates the domain, context , and etc classes.
In this wizard i **didnt** select the option to pluralize the names.
I have a table wich the name is `Error`, and when i try to get all the records of this particular table i get the error message : `Invalid object name 'dbo.Errors'.`

```
 public IQueryable<Error> GetAllErrors()
 {
        return _context.Error.AsQueryable();
 }

 public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var aux = new MessageRepository();
        var errors = aux.GetAllErrors().ToList(); // Exception here
        return View();
  }
```

Why im getting this error?

Comment: From your wording it seems more code-first than database-first. Check that your `Error` class is not mapped to a specific table either with the attribute `[Table()]` or in the DnContext class with something like `context.Entity<Error>.ToTable("Errors");`

Comment: @Tallmaris sorry, i mean 'CodeFirst', but in my domain partial classes i have no attributes like Table or etc. I put manually a atributte [Table("Error")] to fix this issue. But i would like to know why and where the EF pluralize this name.

Comment: Check the `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext class. All the conventions modifications are stored there so maybe there is something in the code that can help...

Comment: @Tallmaris I´ve commented the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: Can you show us the `OnModelCreating` that was there? If you commented it chances are you reverted back to the default behaviour (which is "pluralize all"). Also worth checking are the `Configuration` class and the we.config